# How to read contents of a file to a statically declared variable?

Tags: c, fread

I have a data file in binary where the first four bytes are some integer that I want to read. I simply do:

```c
int * num_rounters_p = malloc(sizeof(int));
fread(num_rounters_p, 4, 1, p_file);

printf("%d\n", *num_routers_p); // 10
```

This works fine (and please tell me if it doesn't!), however I do know the size of this particular value, and so it isn't really necessary to store it dynamically.

Is it possible to do something like

```c
int x = some_read_function(4, 1, p_file);

printf("%d\n", x); // 10
```

Basically storing the value on stack instead of the heap? The code example above is of course not grounded in C, but I hope I got my point across :))

Comment: You appear to be assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`.  Don't make that assumption.

Comment: Why don't you just do `fread(&x, 4, 1, p_file);`?

Comment: Just store it in a plain old `int`? `fread(&im_an_int, sizeof(int), 1, file)`. Too easy?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes! Good advice :)

Comment: @Lundin Yes, indeed. In fact I realized right after posting... Let this post be for all other noobies. :))

Comment: Why `malloc` an `int` value? The size of pointer `num_rounters_p` probably is more than allocated space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be

```
int num_routers;
size_t items_read = fread( &num_routers, sizeof num_routers, 1, p_file );

if ( items_read < 1 )
{
  // read error, handle as appropriate
}
else
{
  // do something with num_routers
}
```

An `int` is not guaranteed to be 4 bytes wide, it's only guaranteed to be *at least* 2 bytes wide, so it's safer to use `sizeof num_routers` than a literal `4`.  Of course, that assumes that the binary file was written on the same platform that you're reading from.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: =sigh= Popped another synapse.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm! Easy fix. Just do:

```c
int num_routers;
fread(&num_routers, sizeof(int), 1, p_file);
```

Comment: Better with `sizeof num_routers`

Comment: All input functions deserve a check of the return value.

Comment: Input functions often fail to read expected data.  `fread()` deserves a test to see if the return value is acceptable.  i.e Was  the expected amount of data truly read?  Else `printf("%d\n", *num_routers_p);` may print  misleading data.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica how can input functions fail to read data you tell them to read??

Comment: "how can input functions fail to read data you tell them to read" --> Many reasons.  (corrupt data, invalid data, loss of communication, scant data, delays, ...) Sounds like a good question to post  for a complete answer.

Comment: @Snusifer Because that's MY name in an orchestra I play in. Here is a picture of my uniform. https://ibb.co/MGzFDNj

Comment: @klutt Wow! What a coincidence. I wonder why they went for that name, and what it means in that context. Dang, I want that uniform now xD

Comment: @Snusifer It has the exact same etymology in my case. It's because I'm using snus. Actually I'm also making it. But the uniform and name is mine. Join the orchestra, and you'll get an own uniform, but the name is already taken. ;)

Comment: @Snusifer Which country? Also Sweden?

Comment: @klutt Norway x)) Whoever founded your orchestra probably thought of the same pun, since you're from Sweden. In that regard, its crazy to name an orchestra Snusifer tbh...

Comment: @Snusifer Oh, it's not the name of the orchestra. It's my nickname in the orchestra. The name of the orchestra is Wijkmanska Blecket

Comment: @klutt so we thought of the same pun? xDD nice. wise men think alike

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229563/discussion-between-klutt-and-snusifer).